# Angular error after install of browser-animations

Tags: angular, npm, ionic4

I have an Ionic4/Angular app in which I recently installed Browser Animations via `npm`. However, I now get this error: `ERROR in node_modules/@angular/animations/browser/browser.d.ts:135:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.`
I have no clue what to do, `npm uninstall @angular/animations/browser` yields no results.

Comment: Can you provide info about your `packaje.json`? Try removing your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file, then run `npm i`

Comment: Try the following:

`ng update --next @angular/cli --force`

`npm install typescript@latest`

Comment: Any luck with this?  I updated to angular 9.2 and typescript 3.8.3 and am getting this error with angular animations.  Specifically in browser.d.ts on this line: 
     
    get players(): AnimationPlayer[];